# Flutter How to enable the remember account and password feature?

Tags: flutter, nuxtjs3

I have a website built with Nuxt3 embedded in a Flutter mobile app using `flutter_inappwebview`.Now I want to save my account and password when successfully logged in, do I need to enable Flutter or Nuxt3 side and how to do it?

[image: Save password on iPhone]

Comment: `how-to` questions are unfortunately not allowed here. What did you tried already?